# 3 Tables 1 Query for Nested Result - Mysql - Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.

**product** table

```
id  name
1   tv
2   phone
```

**category** table

```
id name
1  electronics
2  gift
```

**relation** table

```
pid cid
1   1
2   1
2   2
```

---

**What do I want?**

I want to show products with categories likes this by using sql query and php.

```
<h1>tv</h1>
<span>electronics</span>

<h1>phone</h1>
<span>electronics</span>
<span>gift</span>
```

**What can I do?**

Using JOIN and a foreach I could get the result below. But I do not want that.

```
<h1>tv</h1>
<span>electronics</span>

<h1>phone</h1>
<span>electronics</span>

<h1>phone</h1>
<span>gift</span>
```

**What is your most efficient query and loop method to reach the result?**

Answer (score 0):

if you order by product you can do this

```
while($row=$result->fetch_object()){
$product=$row->product;
$category=$row->category;
if($product==$pcheck){
echo "<span>$category</span>";
}
else{
echo "<h1>$product</h1><span>$category</span>";
}
$pcheck=$product;
}
```

depending on your data you can also do this

```
while($row=$result->fetch_object()){
$x[$row->product][]="<span>$row->category</span>";
}
foreach ($x as $product=>$categories){
echo "<h1>$product</h1>".implode("",$categories);
}
```